# The database system then writes out enough information to disk

Tags: database-design

The text below is from the book Database System Concepts by Silberschatz.

This information that is written out to disk forms a log file or is something other that the log file?

> The database system then writes out enough information to disk that,
> even in the event of a failure, the updates performed by the
> transaction can be re-created when the system restarts after the
> failure. When the last of this information is written out, the
> transaction enters the committed state.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Write-Ahead-Log) is a synopsis of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of [Transaction Journalisation](http://jimgray.azurewebsites.net/papers/thetransactionconcept.pdf) has been release in the 70's by Bernstein and Gray. The algorithm used is based on [ARIES](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebrewer/cs262/Aries.pdf#:%7E:text=ARIES%3A%20A%20Transaction%20Recovery%20Method.%2095%20DB2TM%2C%20IMS%2C,languages%2C%20recoverable%20file%20systems%20and%20transaction-based%20operating%20systems.) for all the Relational DBMS.

The way that does it is quite simple. Every write that must occurs in the database (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, but also CREATE, ALTER, DROP, GRANT...) need a safety net, until the all work is done. To do this, the values before modifiying the database state is physically copyed into a special storage called "transaction log". After the data has been modified in memory, this transaction is marked as "done" in the transaction log, if no exception is raised. That is the COMMIT. In case of an exception (or a voluntary cancel of the writes) that's the ROLLBACK, and previous values are replaced in the memory.

I say that data are written in memory... Not on disk. But the problem is that a server has generally not enough memory to store inside the RAM all the datas.. Also, on a regular tempo, a process called CHECKPOINT is started in order to transcribe, on the data storage, the data modified in memory between two passages.

CHECKPOINT occurs generally on different objectives : a limit of amount of data, a limit of time and a limit on memory pressure...

Let me know if I am not clear or you want some complementary explanations

I am writing a french book about SQL and relational databases that explains all that folks...

To be complet, please read ["Database Management Systems 3rd Edition by Johannes Ramakrishnan Raghu page 536"](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqvZfiQYoNpBihpRDO1qnqTIsD-7?e=vyfQbF)

Answer (score 1):

For relational databases at least (I assume that is the focus of this book), yes it is a log file of some sort. The exact name it goes by may vary, though.

| RDBMS | Log Name |
| --- | --- |
| Oracle | [Redo Log](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/onlineredo001.htm#ADMIN11302) |
| SQL Server | [Transaction Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) |
| Postgres | [WAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/wal-intro.html) (Write-ahead log) |

...and so on. The Wikipedia page for [Transaction Log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_log) is also a redirect from "Binary Log" and "Journal (Computing)" as examples of more synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about the "moment of commit" for a transaction. A transaction is a suite of one or several changes made to the data: insertions of new rows, deletion of existing rows, updates of existing rows. It could even do something like inserting a row and then updating it. All together those changes form a "transaction".

Transactions have well known properties described by the acronym ACID (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID):

- Atomicity
- Consistency
- Isolation
- Durability

The most important here are Atomicity and Durability.

**Atomicity** means that **all** the changes in a transaction must be applied - or **none** must be applied: you cannot have a transaction executing a few changes, then failing and leaving those changes in the database. That would leave the database in an inconsistent state. The Atomicity is generally guaranteed thanks to a log, generally called the "**undo log**": the "before" images of the changed data are saved in that log, before writing the changes out onto the actual tables. If anything bad happens (application failure, database failure, ...), then the database system will automatically restore the data to its prior state by reading from that log. This is called the "write ahead log" principle, meaning that the before image is saved **before** the data is written on the actual tables. Once the transaction is committed, then the undo log for that transaction can be forgotten.

**Durability** further guarantees that, once a transaction is committed, then the effects of that transaction (all the changes) are guaranteed to be permanent. This is where the **redo log** comes into play. The redo log is here to guarantee that, should you lo lose any media - like a disk crash - you will never lose any data. Of course you can restore the media from a backup: but that will return the database to a state before running all those transactions. So a recovery includes two phases: restoring the backup, then **rolling forward** by reading from the redo log and essentially, replaying all the changes made by all applications since the backup, right up until the point of failure.

And here comes the interesting bit that you quote:

> The database system then writes out enough information to disk that, even in the event of a failure, the updates performed by the transaction can be re-created when the system restarts after the failure. When the last of this information is written out, the transaction enters the committed state.

The traditional way of committing a transaction is to wait until all changes have been written to all tables updated in that transaction. This is actually quite slow, since those writes can be random. And it is actually not strictly necessary: once the changes are written to the redo-log, then they are as good as written to the actual tables: if something bad happens (a system crash, a media crash), the updates performed by the transaction can be recreated from the information written to the redo log. The writes to the actual tables still take place - but lazily, after the log was written (or while the log is being written to). But they will be written eventually.

The good thing about that approach is that log writes are **sequential**. They can be buffered in memory and they are written sequentially, a faster process than the many random writes to update the actual tables. Also, since all concurrent transactions write to the same global redo-log, all those log writes can be **combined**: the changes are accumulated in memory buffers, and those buffers are pushed onto the redo log. Each buffer can contain changes from multiple transactions.

Another good thing is that it makes it easy to identify the **moment of commit**: that very precise moment in the life of a transaction where it is guaranteed to be persistent. That must be an atomic operation: a single operation that is guaranteed to either fail entirely or succeed entirely. That operation is a "flush" I/O: an operation that flushes out the buffers that contain all my changes onto the redo log. More generally, it is the final write of the final buffer. Once that completes (= the I/O subsystem returns "success"), the database system can then confidently return from the commit() call to the application. The application is now certain that the changes are **persisted** - they may not yet be in the database tables, but they are in the redo log, and that is all that matters.